# How to tweet an image using PHP from my website?

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to tweet an image using php. I have read the documentation and followed a some tutorials. I don't have any problem when sending a message; however, it does not work with images. I can not find where my mistake is, can anyone help?? I would deeply appreciate it.

```
 <?php
        $comments = $_POST['comment'];
        if (isset($_POST['Twitter']))

        {

    require_once('twitter/codebird-php/src/codebird.php');
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("xxxxxx","xxxxxx");
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");

    $params = array(
    'status' => $comments,
    'media[]' => "/images/image1.jpg"
    );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

    echo "You have posted your message succesfully";

    }

    else{

        echo "You havent posted anythingh";
    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply Twitter the fully qualified URI to your image.

You have the following code:

```
$params = array(
'status' => $comments,
'media[]' => "/images/image1.jpg"
);
```

Unfortunately, that's not a complete URL to an image, it's a *relative* URL. Instead, you need to provide something along the lines of this:

```
$params = array(
'status' => $comments,
'media[]' => "http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg"
);
```

In addition, according to the [Twitter API v1 documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update), you need to use [`statuses/update_with_media`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media) instead of [`statuses/update`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update).

If you are using Twitter API v1, Twitter also recommends [using v1.1 instead](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media).

Comment: Actually a tried to use statuses_updateWithMedia before, but it didn't work either. I need to look into the major changes API v1.1. Today is my first day using twitter apis and I am still a little confused.