# Tweet status and picture with PHP using TwitterAPIExchange

Tags: php, twitter

I have written the following PHP function (see below) that allows me to tweet either a staus or a status+image.

The status update works fine, but if I pass an image name (and the fact that strlen($image) !=0 dictates a different path through the function), it does not tweet, nor do I get an error.

I have tried manually putting the image path+name into the 'media[]' element of the array, but cannot get this to work.

I have even tried

```
'media[]' => "http://www.website.com/twitter/images/pic.jpg");
```

... which is the full path name to the file, as suggested in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665952/how-to-tweet-an-image-using-php-from-my-website). This does actually give me an error:

{"errors":[{"code":189,"message":"Error creating status."}]}

I have followed carefully a few other forum posts, but after a couple of days I am getting a little frustrated? :-).

Any help appreciated.

```
public function postTweet($tweet, $imagesPath, $image) {
$url      = $this->baseTwitterURL . 'statuses/update.json';
$urlMedia = $this->baseTwitterURL . 'statuses/update_with_media.json';

$postURL = "";

$requestMethod = 'POST';

if(strlen($image) == 0) {
   $postfields = array(
   'status' => $tweet);

    $postURL = $url;
}
else {
    $imagetoPost = $imagesPath . $image;
    $postfields = array(
      'status' => $tweet,
      'media[]' => "@{$imagetoPost}");
    $postURL = $urlMedia;
};

try{        
   $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($this->settings);
   $postfields[status] . $this->newline;

   echo $twitter->buildOauth($postURL, $requestMethod)
                ->setPostfields($postfields)
                ->performRequest();

   } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
   }
} // postTweet
```

Comment: I have also just tried "manually" tweeting the same image and that works.

Comment: Can you please share the output of the following: `$this->baseTwitterURL` and `$tweet`?

Comment: I have also tried using a very short status ("test") just to see if it was an issue with the length of the status

Comment: As an aside, [upload_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media) is deprecated, so if it's not working anyway you may as well look into changing your code to use the replacement API method.

Comment: $this->baseTwitterURL gives 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/Tweet'

Comment: $tweet give 'Tweet for Stack Exchange'

Comment: Thansk fro the deprecation comment - so uploading media and udating statuses use the same URL call?

I am trying that now.

Comment: I opened up a new [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863919/tweet-status-and-picture-with-php-using-twitterapiexchange-part-2) as I thought it would be easier.

Thanks so far