# Tweet status and picture with PHP using TwitterAPIExchange (part 2)

Tags: php, twitter

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862711/tweet-status-and-picture-with-php-using-twitterapiexchange), where I was struggling to get status and media to upload to Twitter, using PHP and TwitterAPIExchange.

I was given some good advice, but it still won't work. That is, I don't get an error, but the tweet does not appear.

I thought it was easier to write a new post as the previous one would not allow me to add more than a few hundred characters.

I have now re-written the function (shown at the end) so that it will ONLY tweet a status+image. This makes it shorter and, I hope, simpler to follow. I have also got rid on the deprecated call, as advised.

I have also included a dump of the key variables. These come out as:

```
$tweet = 'Test for Stack Exchange'

$imagesPath = '/twitter/images/GXK/'

$image = 'graham.jpg'

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'

$imageToPost = '/twitter/images/GXK/graham.jpg'
```

I have also tried putting in the full path name to the image, that is:

```
'media[]' => "@{http://www.graham-kendall.com/twitter/images/GXK/graham.jpg}");
```

I have also tried:

```
'media' => "http://www.graham-kendall.com/twitter/images/GXK/graham.jpg");
```

This **DOES** actually tweet the text but **NOT** the image.

Any help appreciated.

**The Function**

```
public function postImageTweet($tweet, $imagesPath, $image) {
    $url         = $this->baseTwitterURL . 'statuses/update.json';
    $imageToPost = $imagesPath . $image;

    // Display key variables
    echo "tweet: "          . $tweet          . $newline;
    echo "imagesPath: "     . $imagesPath     . $newline;
    echo "image: "          . $image          . $newline;
    echo "url: "            . $url            . $newline;
    echo "imageToPost: "    . $imageToPost    . $newline;

    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
      'status' => $tweet,
      'media[]' => "@{http://www.graham-kendall.com/twitter/images/GXK/graham.jpg}");

    try{        
       $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($this->settings);
       echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->setPostfields($postfields)
                    ->performRequest();

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
} // postImageTweet
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$url` has to be this:

```
$url = $this->baseTwitterURL . 'statuses/update_with_media.json';
```

If you don't use 'with_media' that won't work.

Comment: Thanks. I am still struggling with this, but gradually getting there. Once I do, I'll post the answer!

Comment: @Graham -  did you save this?